# How to keep toast orientation after minimizing activity?

Tags: java, android, toast, landscape

At all time, the phone is in landscape mode.

My activity is in landscape mode (and has a landscape version) and it displays a toast, which shows also in landscape mode.
Just after the toast, I minimize the activity:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

The toast continues to display, but rotates now to 90 degrees in portrait mode (which is probably related to the mode of the home screen).

So far I found only this [SO post with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123684/how-to-set-toast-orientation-while-opened-in-another-intent).

Is there any way to force display the toast in landscape mode? (The toast was initiated in landscape mode, so it shouldn't rotate 90 degrees and it should stay in landscape mode)

What I want is: when I press a button, the activity disappears (we would then see any app behind or the home screen) and the toast is shown. All in landscape mode. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found a convenient and easy way to achieve this!

First, I tried with a time to first have the toast being displayed and the the moveTaskToBack. But this did not work. The moveTaskToBack was stronger than the timer and the toast continued to appear in portrait mode when the mobile phone was still in landscape mode.

And then I thought about tweaking the imageView. What if one could display it with a rotation of 90 degrees? And this is the solution. It works.

In your layout, add the following line to your imageview (or any other element) to rotate it by 90 degrees:

```
android:rotation="90"
```

and then you have to play and test your mobile to position your elements (not only imageView but also buttons, textview etc.) where you want on the screen.

I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texttoast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="430dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/imagetoast"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:text="My text here"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagetoast"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```